# Missing sample_data from Anaconda matplotlib package

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda

Anaconda 5.1, matplotlib 2.2.2 on Win 10 x64

`matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data` is missing from matplotlib package so a number of samples and tutorials that expect to load them with `matplotlib.cbook.get_sample_data()` fails.

Tried to install `mpl_sample_data` package from `conda-forge` but files are installed into the parent directory `matplotlib\mpl-data` and not `matplotlib\mpl-data\sample_data` where they should be and `get_sample_data()` expects to find them as default.

Any suggestion on how to have a *complete* matplotlib installation on Anaconda?

Thanks

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge mpl_sample_data` seems to work correctly by now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. 
First, I install matplotlib package independently using the official command 'python -mpip install -U matplotlib'. https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/users/installing.html#windows
Then, you will have the sample_data folder in your Python directory.
Second, I copy the sample_data folder from Python directory to anaconda's matplotlib\mpl-data\ directory.

Comment: directly `pip install -U matplotlib` inside the virtual environment works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. 
I see that Anaconda recipe for `matplotlib` explicitly exclude `sample_data`, i don't understand why, but instead of bothering with packages i simply downloaded `matplotlib` from github and used `sample_data` from it.

Answer (score 0):

Installed matplotlib using anaconda, facing the same Problem. 
This worked for me, copy the following folder 
[sample_data](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/sample_data)
in your anaconda installation viz.,

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\

(I've installed it in C drive).

Or better still you can clone [matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git) repository from git
and then install using command:

```
python setup.py install
```

Hope this helps.